# Birthday paradox python - incorrect probability output

Tags: python, birthday-paradox

I am having issues with the programming the birthday paradox in Python. The birthday paradox basically says that if there are 23 people in a class, the probability that two of them will have the same birthday is 50%.

I have attempted to code this paradox in Python, however it keeps coming back with a probability of closer to 25%. I am very new to Python and so no doubt there is a simple solution to this problem. Here is my code:

```
import random


def random_birthdays():
    bdays = []
    bdays = [random.randint(1, 365) for i in range(23)]
    bdays.sort()
    for x in bdays:
        while x < len(bdays)-1:
            if bdays[x] == bdays[x+1]:
                print(bdays[x])
                return True
            x+=1
        return False

count = 0
for i in range (1000):
if random_birthdays() == True:
    count = count + 1


print('In a sample of 1000 classes each with 23 pupils, there were', count, 'classes with individuals with the same birthday')
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? Asking us to debug your code from you in its entirety isn't appropriate.

Comment: And the answer to your second question is the single responsibility principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error in this line:

```
for x in bdays:
```

should be

```
for x in range(len(bdays)):
```

Because you need to iterate over indices of birthdays but not birthdays itself.

And one more optimization:

```
count = 0
for i in range (1000):
    if random_birthdays() == True:
       count = count + 1
```

can be replaced by

```
count  = sum(random_birthdays() for _ in range(1000))
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides, your function should be implemented like this:

```
import random

def random_birthdays(pupils):
    bdays = [random.randint(1, 365) for _ in range(pupils)]
    return pupils > len(set(bdays))
```

This eliminates so many sources of error.

This can be called as @Zefick has indicated:

```
count  = sum(random_birthdays(23) for _ in range(1000))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
def find(p):
    return math.ceil(math.sqrt(2*365*math.log(1/(1-p))));

print(find(0.25))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, please consider adding some explanation, so that person, who asked the question, can understand you better.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I wrote it.

```
# check probability for birthday reoccurance for a class of 23 students or the birthday paradox
import random as r

def check_date(students):
    date=[]
    count=0
    
    for i in range(students): # Generate a random age for n students
        date+=[r.randint(1,365)] # entire sample list for age is created
        
    for letter in date: # check if the date repeats anywhere else
        if date.count(letter)>=2: # Use count it's simple & easy.
            count+=1
            
    return count # count of a pair of students having same b.day

def simulations(s,students):
    result=[] # empty list to update data.
    simulation_match=0
    
    for i in range(s):
        result+=[check_date(students)] # get a sample list for all the students in 'n' no. of simulations
        
        if check_date(students)>1: # if atleat 2 students have same b.day in each simulation
            simulation_match+=1
            
    return simulation_match,s,int(simulation_match/s*100),'%'

simulations(1000,23) # 1000 simulations with 23 students sample size
```

OUT: `(494, 1000, 49, '%')`  ** the percentage part varies based on the random int generated**